# Passing for loop values to an API call field

Tags: python, api, for-loop

I am in need of taking multiple values from a for loop and passing them to an api call. what is the best way for me to do this?

the values being referenced are 'id's and I will need each of them to populate the id requirement in the api call.

*** MY for loop

```
response = json.loads(z)

for d in response:
    for key, value in d['to'].items():
        if key == 'id':
            print(value)
```

*** API Call

```
id = '' # str |
content_type = 'application/json' # str |  (default to application/json)
accept = 'application/json' # str |  (default to application/json)
fields = '' # str | Use a space seperated string of field parameters to include the data in the response. If omitted, the default list of fields will be returned.  (optional) (default to )
filter = 'filter_example' # str | A filter to apply to the query. (optional)
x_org_id = '' # str |  (optional) (default to )



api_response = api_instance.systemusers_get(id, content_type, accept, fields=fields, filter=filter, x_org_id=x_org_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out yourself, you need a string. So you have to add these ids to some string when you loop over them. So let's start by just making an empty string. And then, when we loop, instead of printing the ID, we can *concatenate* it to the string

```
string = ""
for d in response:
    for key, value in d['to'].items():
        if key == 'id':
            string += value
```

and then later:

```
id = string
```

Now of course I don't know what format this string needs to be in for that specific API. But you should be able to adapt the pattern to, for example, comma separate the values if need be.

(Note, I use the name string to be clear in the context of this question, but come up with a better variable name, obviously)

EDIT: How to make multiple API Calls

If you can only send one ID per API call, then there's two things you can do. Make the calls in the loop as well, or save this ids to a list. In either case, it's going to help if you wrap your API call into a function:

```
def make_api_call(id)
    id = id
    content_type = 'application/json' # str |  (default to application/json)
    accept = 'application/json' # str |  (default to application/json)
    fields = '' # str | Use a space seperated string of field parameters to include the data in the response. If omitted, the default list of fields will be returned.  (optional) (default to )
    filter = 'filter_example' # str | A filter to apply to the query. (optional)
    x_org_id = '' # str |  (optional) (default to )
    api_response = api_instance.systemusers_get(id, content_type, accept, fields=fields, filter=filter, x_org_id=x_org_id)
```

Now, you can call this in the loop like so:

```
for d in response:
    for key, value in d['to'].items():
        if key == 'id':
            make_api_call(value)
```

Or you can build a list and then run the calls on that list:

```
all_ids = []

for d in response:
    for key, value in d['to'].items():
        if key == 'id':
            all_ids.append(value)

for id in all_ids:
    make_api_call(id)
```

(Note, I'm using the variable name 'id' to be in parity with the question. However '_id' is preferred, because 'id' is a builtin.)

Comment: how do I get each id to output as a seperate string? the solution you provided just adds all of the id's to one string

Comment: Yea, that's what you asked for... You provided a variable called id with comment that it must be a string. Please edit the question if you mean something else.

Comment: Does the API need a list? What must you send? Multiple calls?

Comment: yeah I think I will probably need a list. The for loop is returning 2 id's at value. 5c9941fcdd2eeb6a6787916e
5cc9055fcc5781152ca6eeb8 I need to create a string's of these id's as they are returned from the for loop and pass them to the api call

Comment: Sorry @JasonFrazee but can I ask for more clarity. Does the API accept more than one ID per request? I'm trying to understand whether you want to make multiple API calls each with one ID, or one API call where you send all of the IDs in one request.

Comment: Unfortunately the api accepts one id at a time. I will have to make a separate api call for each id

Comment: @JasonFrazee updated answer. You said something above about the loop "returning 2ids at value". I'm not sure what you meant by that. If you need to do something to the dictionary values in order to extract the ids, just do that in the loop before you make the api calls, or before you add the ids to the list.

Comment: You have been super helpful! last question if I needed to extract the response from the for loop after the api call how would i do so. Instead of printing the values I need to store them and use them for another api call.

Comment: @JasonFrazee just add "return api_response" to the end of the make_api_call function. Then you can do "response = make_api_call(value) in the loop, and append the response to a list. If that doesn't make sense, I'm going to suggest that you open a new question, Each question on SO should only deal with one issue, so I'm not going to edit the answer again. Please accept if it solved the original issue.